# Mounting docker volumes to conatiners

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I have seen that once i have ran my container then its not possible to attach any volume to it.

I was thinking of creating a container which has suppose 2 volumes mounted from host

```
Container A

-v /host/data/vol1: /vol1
-v /host/data/vol2: /vol2
```

Now in Container B i will have

`docker run --volumes-from=containerA`

Now i want to know that if add another volume in conatiner A

```
-v /host/data/vol1: /vol1
-v /host/data/vol2: /vol2
-v /host/data/vol3: /vol3
```

Now will that now be availabe on Contaner B or not